# I can't get npm start to run

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

I'm just created a *react project using NPM with the npx create-react-app*. Afterward, I tried starting the development server and got an error message.

I have tried looking at the error code and log but I am not sure what to do.

The terminal error message is

> ```
> /Users/selina/Desktop/reactv2/node_modules/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js:28
> return (new fsevents(path)).on('fervent', callback).start();
> ```

TypeError: `fsevents is not a constructor`

Comment: I deleted all the node files from my computer and reinstall node and npm and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to root permission. I had the same issue in MacOS and i solved by 
`sudo npm cache clean --force
sudo npm uninstall
sudo npm install`

Hope this helps.. do it with root user

Comment: Well I tried to sudo npm uninstall and I get the error: npm ERR! npm uninstall [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]... [--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--no-save]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: un, unlink, remove, rm, r

Answer (score 0):

npx depends on specific npm version there could be some issue in these number mismatch

you can try with **npm init**

```
npm init create-app myfirtsproject
cd myfirtsproject
npm start or yarn start
```